# Journals missed even though I'm thorough

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to know why I miss some journals/satchels. I am very thorough when I search through my map and I'm often surprised to see that after I pick up Journal 1, I then pick up Journal 10. To make matters worse, if I then find another of the same satchel, it gives me Gold instead of Journal 2 (or any other I missed).

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The locations of many of the Journals and Satchels is random, and only a random selection of each will spawn in a particular game world. You will not find all of them in one playthrough. Each of the spawns is unique, so picking up the same one twice is a possibility and the second time you pick it up you will get gold - this is normal.

The intention is that you will find the ones that you need at a later date on subsequent playthroughs.

This is not the case for all journals, some journals become available at specific parts of the story and can be found by looking in a specific place at a specific time (for example [Leah's Journal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63589/27134)) while some will always appear in the same place but the place itself might not be part of your generated game world (since the game world is randomly generated each time you start a new game).

Here are some additional resources that should help you locate the ones that you're missing:

- [Where are the Act 1 lore books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70083/27134)
- [Where are the act 2 lore books](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70663/27134)
- [Where are the Act 3 lore books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/69132/27134)
- [Where do I find Leah's journal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63589/27134)
- [Are books generated randomly or are they found in set places?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67199/27134)
- [Where can I find Report from Wortham and Villager's Journal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67342/27134)